# Is it possible to define a linear transformation for every pair of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to define a linear transformation for every pair of n dimensional vector spaces. My thought process has led me to a possible contradiction to this in using the zero vector. Is it possible to map the zero vector to any other vector?

Comment: "*Is it possible to map the zero vector to any other vector?*"  Using a linear transformation, of course not.  The zero vector (*of the domain*) *always* gets mapped to the zero vector (*of the codomain*)...but... what is the exact wording of the original question?  Is it possible to define a linear transformation between any pair of vector **spaces**?  The answer to that is of course yes, trivially the map when sends every element in the domain to the zero element in the codomain is linear.  There are of course other examples too depending on the dimension of each space.

Comment: For the related, but different question of if for any nonzero $u$ and $v$ if there exists a linear transformation $T$ such that $T(u)=v$ the answer is again of course yes.

Comment: @JMoravitz Vector spaces. Apologies. Corrected the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to map the zero vector to any other vector?

No, that's not possible. It follows from the (definition of) linearity, that the zero vector must be mapped to the zero vector. Let $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation between vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over some field $K$, then you have for any scalar $\alpha \in K$ and ${\bf 0_V} \in V$:
$$T\left(\alpha \cdot{\bf 0_V}\right)=\alpha \,T\left({\bf 0_V}\right)
\implies T\left({\bf 0_V}\right)=T\left(0 \cdot{\bf 0_V}\right)=0 \,T\left({\bf 0_V}\right)= {\bf 0_W}$$

> I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to define a linear transformation for every pair of n dimensional vectors.

I assume you meant to say: define a linear transformation between two arbitrary $n$-dimensional vector spaces (over *the same field* - see comment by celtschk below). The answer is then **yes** and the dimensions needn't even be the same... With the notation above, define $T$ as:
$$T : V \to W : {\bf v} \mapsto {\bf 0_W}$$
The transformation that trivially maps every element ${\bf v} \in V$ to the zero vector ${\bf 0_W} \in W$. You can easily verify that this is indeed a linear transformation, though perhaps a *boring* one :-).

Comment: I see I'm a bit late, typesetting took longer than expected :-/.

Comment: Sorry. Correction. It was vector spaces and not vectors.

Comment: @Sithe Alright, that's what I assumed.

Comment: "I assume you meant to say: define a linear transformation between two arbitrary $n$-dimensional vector spaces. The answer is then **yes**" — strictly speaking, the answer is **no.** A linear transformation can only be found for vector spaces over the same field. There's no linear map from $\mathbb Z_2^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$, although they even have the same dimension.

Comment: @celtschk I assumed it was clear to consider $T : V \to W$ over _the same field_, but I'll add it explicitly for completeness. Edit: done and referred to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

If $V$ and $W$ are vector *spaces* (over the same field, e.g. both real vector spaces) and $B$ is a basis for $V$, then for every function $f:B\to W$, there is a unique linear transformation $T:V\to W$ such that $T(b)=f(b)$ for all $b\in B$.  So yes, it is always possible, and moreover there are $|W|^{\dim(V)}$ ways to do it.

When it comes to specific vectors, you can do whatever you want to the elements of a linearly independent set (such as a basis), but with a linearly dependent set you are restricted by definition of linearity.  If $T$ is linear and $a_1 v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots a_n v_n=0$, then $a_1 T(v_1)+a_2T(v_2)+\cdots a_n T(v_n)=0$.

A particular example of the above that follows more directly from the definition of linear is that $T(0)=0$ if $T$ is linear.  For the next simplest case, if $v\neq 0$, then $v$ can be mapped anywhere by a linear transformation.  However, you cannot at the same time map $2 v$ wherever you want, because $T(2v)=2T(v)$.

In the case where $V$ is the zero vector space, its only element gets sent to the zero vector in $W$.  Just for fun, note that in the context of the first sentence, $B$ is the empty set, and the zero map is the unique linear extension of the unique map from $\varnothing$ to $W$.